# Hierarchical data in Pandas - Copy data across all "child" values that share the same "parent" value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out a way to carry over data, in this case user information ('email_address', 'name'), to all sub-companies ('companyID') that share the same parent company ('parent_companyID').

My sample DataFrame is:

```
In [1]: sample_data = pd.DataFrame(
{'companyID': {0: 112, 1: 223, 2: 434, 3: 777, 4: 790},
 'email_address': {0: '112email@gmail.com',  1: '', 2: '434email@gmail.com', 3: '777email@gmail.com', 4: ''},
 'name': {0: 'Joe', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'George'},
 'parent_companyID': {0: 555, 1: 555, 2: 555, 3: 999, 4: 999}}
)
```

or for better readability:

```
    companyID   email_address        name    parent_companyID
0   112         112email@gmail.com   Joe         555
1   223                                          555
2   434         434email@gmail.com               555
3   777         777email@gmail.com               999
4   790                              George      999
```

I've done a lot of searching and can't seem to find a similar question that helps me solve this problem. I've taken many stabs at doing this via MultiIndex but haven't come to anything close to the desired outcome, which is:

```
    companyID   email_address        name    parent_companyID
0   112         112email@gmail.com   Joe         555
1   112                                          555
2   112         434email@gmail.com               555
3   223         112email@gmail.com   Joe         555
4   223                                          555
5   223         434email@gmail.com               555
6   434         112email@gmail.com   Joe         555
7   434                                          555    
8   434         434email@gmail.com               555
9   777         777email@gmail.com               999
10  777                              George      999
11  790         777email@gmail.com               999
12  790                              George      999
```

I hope to avoid accomplishing this outcome via some horrific loop, though that's the only way I can think to solve this. The process will be applied to a data set of hundreds of thousands of rows but will not be run often, so efficiency is a consideration but not a hard requirement. If it comes to it, I'll go the loop route but I figure there has to be a better way. Any help, even if it's simply pointing me in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated! I've been pulling my hair out for days on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self Merge!**

- `pd.merge` with one's self and look inward
- conveniently place a suffix for the left half of merge
- I want everything except `'companyID'` from right half of merge so I left it's suffix as a null string
- I only want `'companyID'` from the left half... notice I made the suffixe `' '` a single space.  I did this so that my renaming later would make use of a simple `str.strip`
- rearrange my columns in which I slice the final result to get the order I want.

---

```
on = 'parent_companyID'
mrg = sample_data.merge(sample_data, on=on, suffixes=[' ', ''])
cols = sample_data.columns.tolist()
cols.remove('companyID')
cols.insert(0, 'companyID ')
mrg[cols].rename(columns=str.strip)

    companyID       email_address     name  parent_companyID
0         112  112email@gmail.com  112Name               555
1         112                                            555
2         112  434email@gmail.com                        555
3         223  112email@gmail.com  112Name               555
4         223                                            555
5         223  434email@gmail.com                        555
6         434  112email@gmail.com  112Name               555
7         434                                            555
8         434  434email@gmail.com                        555
9         777  777email@gmail.com                        999
10        777                      790Name               999
11        790  777email@gmail.com                        999
12        790                      790Name               999
```